# How to get localstorage data inside vuex state with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm building a shopping cart with Nuxt. but when i refresh the page the basket automatically empties.

I try librairies like vuex-persist , vuex-persistedstate ...
but I did not have a solution.

Now Im looking a way to get the initial state of cart directly from local storage like this.

```
state: {
      cart: [] //here what i want => window.localStorage.getItem("cart")
    }
```

Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access localStorage only in browser. Its not accessible during SSR.
So you need to create create a mutation in vuex store that will do what u want and commit it in mounted hook ( mounted executed only in browser ).

E.g.

```
...
mounted() {
 this.$store.commit('myMutation', window.localStorage.getItem("cart")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aldarund i will do that.

Answer (score 1):

use nuxt-vuex-localstorage
it works great and syncs with vuex